# It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

HI guys i am having a problem uploading my website to a server. i get the following error

```
Configuration Error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Source Error: 


    Line 14: 
    Line 15: 
    Line 16:     <profile>
    Line 17:       <properties>
    Line 18:         <add name="FirstName" />

    Source File: D:\Year1415\courseworks\CC6001\cc6001taz0051\site\web.config    Line: 16
```

Can someone please help me. I need to upload my assignment to the webserver before tuesday. any help would be grateful. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Config files in .NET stack one on top of the other, with the lowest level being machine.config which applies to all .NET applications on a machine. Some settings cannot be overridden, and attempting to do so gives this error.

This particular error (given the section mentioned) can be caused by not setting an IIS virtual directory up as an application. See the response in this post:

http://forums.iis.net/t/1197180.aspx

In IIS 7 a virtual directory is not set up as an application by default.

In IIS right click the folder and select "Convert to application".

Comment: can i do this on my home computer then copy the converted site to usb and upload it on the university computers? thanks

Comment: No IIS is a server resource. It has to be done on the server itself (though it will work almost exactly the same on your university server as your home PC).

Comment: but i cannot access the control panel and administrative functions on the uni pcs.... is there any other way around this

Comment: First you need to assert that this is definitely the problem. How are you deploying it to your uni server? Has the uni set a site up for you? If so chances are it will already be configured correctly.

Comment: I have tried uploading another website to my server and it works perfectly. I have uploaded many websites in the past without any problem. But this website is giving me problems for some reason :(